# Integrating Dispatch Actions in Container Component Pattern

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I'm completely confused on how to integrate the Container and Component Pattern. I've been reviewing examples all morning and nothing seems to be clicking. How I have been worked with React previously  on my first project was fetch the data within my view components and then pass that data down as props using the `@connect` which works, but in an "automagically" way to me at this time.

```
import React;
...
import {action} from 'path/to/action.js';

@connect((store) => {return{ key: store.property}});

export class Component{
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.dispatch(action());
  }
}
```

As I'm working more with React I want to learn the more "correct" way of building out with Redux and understand on a deeper level what is happening.

What I have setup is

```
index.jsx (This renders all of my HOCs)
  |    
  App.jsx (Container)
    |
    Auth.jsx (Component)
      |
      Layout.jsx (Component) - Contains app content
      --or--
      AuthError.jsx (Component) - 401 unauthenticated error page
```

Authentication is handled through an outside resource so this app will not control anything with Logging in or out. There will be no log in/out states simply receiving an object from an API that identifies the User Role & Authenticated Boolean.

What I would like to happen is when the App loads, it will fetch data from a mock API, [JSON Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). From there it will render the Auth component. The Auth component will take in `props` from `App.jsx` and either render the `Layout.jsx` or `AuthError.jsx`.

Where I'm running into issues is how this should be integrated. I'm going to omit lines of code I don't think absolutely pertain to the question.

**store.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reducer from './reducers';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, createLogger());

export default createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(middleware));
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import store from './store.js';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './containers/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { authenticateUser } from '../actions/authActions.js';
import Auth from '../components/Auth.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        authenticated: false // this needs to be set
      };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('APP PROPS', this.props);
    // this.props.actions.authenticateUser();
    authenticateUser(); // this runs but doesn't run the dispatch function
    // What I think needs to happen here Dispatch an Action and then setState referring back to how I would previous build with React Redux.
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Auth app_name={ApplicationName} authenticated={this.state.authenticated} {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log('redux store auth state', state);
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(authenticateUser, dispatch) };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**Auth.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import AuthError from './AuthError.jsx';
import Layout from './Layout.jsx';

export default function Auth(props) {
  console.log('AUTH PROPS', props);
  const renderLayout = () => {
    if (props.authenticated == true) {
        return <Layout app_name={props.app_name} />;
    } else {
        return <AuthError />;
    }
  };
  return <Route path="/" render={renderLayout} />;
}
```

**authReducer.js**

```
export default function reducer(
  state = {
    authenticated: null
  },
  action
) {
switch (action.type) {
  case 'AUTH_SUCCESSFUL': {
    return {
      ...state,
        authenticated: action.payload.authenticated
    };
    break;
    }
    case 'AUTH_REJECTED': {
      return {
        ...state,
        authenticated: false
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

**authActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function authenticateUser() {
console.log('authenticate user action has been called');
return function(dispatch) {
  // nothing runs within this block so it's leading me to believe nothing is being `dispatch`ed
    console.log('dispatch', dispatch);
    axios
        .get('localhost:3004/auth')
        .then(response => {
          dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_SUCCESSFUL', payload: response.data });
            console.log('response', response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_REJECTED', payload: err });
            console.log('error', err);
        });
    };
}
```

Right now inside of `App.jsx` I can console the state of the `authReducer` and I can call `authenticateUser()` in my actions. But when I call `authenticateUser()` the return dispatch function doesn't run. Should I be dispatching the auth action in `App.jsx`? Or should I be dispatching the auth in `Auth.jsx` as a prop to then have `App.jsx` fetch the data? Just a bit lost on breaking this apart and what piece should be doing what work.

Comment: in `App.js` why did you comment out `// this.props.actions.authenticateUser();`  and instead run it directly? `authenticateUser();` you mapped it to `props` via an `actions` object

Comment: More of an illustrative purpose of different attempts. I went through a lot of examples trying to connect the dots. The first attempt was running it directly, followed by creating that actions in the return of `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: Ok, when you use the `mapDispatchToProps` like that you should use this sysntax `this.props.actions.authenticateUser()`. that being said, you shouldn't use ajax requests in `componentWillMount`, its the same as using it in the constructor, the `render` method could potentially be invoked before the ajax request has finished. by the way you shouldn't use `componentWillMount` method at all and use the `constructor`  instead. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: Alright that's clear enough, I've modified and running the dispatch within the `constructor()` function instead of `componentWillMount`.

Comment: No, i meant use the `constructor` instead of `componentWillMount` in general, but still, you shouldn't call ajax requests inside them (not in the `componentWillMount` nor the `constructor`). for ajax requests you should use the `componentDidMount`

Comment: So I've read previously some issues with `componentDidMount` with lifecycles so have always stuck with `componentWillMount` so I didn't read over that. Appreciate you reinforcing your point see now where it clearly states "If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.".

Comment: I wanted to direct this to you, since you've been really helpful with the lifecycle hooks. I have my call in `componentWillMount(){this.props.authenticateUser()}`. 

should I be using `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){this.setState({ authenticated: nextProps.authenticated.authenticated}` to update the App state? 

Doing that works as expected, but I'm not looking for as expected as compared to what is more correct.

Or just `return <Auth authenticated={this.props.authenticated.authenticated} />;` which also works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your authenticateUser returns a function, you need to literally run the function. The right way to do that is to add a property in your mapDispatchToProps

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
     return { authenticateUser: () => dispatch(authenticateUser()) };
 };`

Then, in your componentWillMount function, call 
`this.props.authenticateUer()`

[Check this](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Comment: Get rid of the actions props in mapDispatchToProps. It keeps telling me the format is incorrect when I tried to edit my answer, so I just post it here in the comments.

Comment: One thing I got tripped up on is the `authenticateUser: dispatch(authActions.authenticateUser())`. I'm wondering where you got `authActions` as that isn't a function. Reducing to `authenticateUser: dispatch(authenticateUser())` is firing.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I should have made it more clear. I usually do import * as authenActions from "path to the file" , and then use the function. `authenActions.authenticateUser()`

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help in getting this to work. I've also seen `import * from 'actions-file.js;' in several pieces of material I've been reading and your comment brought more clarity on that methodology.

Comment: `import * as moduleName from path_to_file` helps to track the source of the imported object. It's very helpful when you need to import many things from different files.

Comment: Still running into an error

`componentDidMount(){console.log('auth actions', this.props); this.props.authenticateUser();`

Returns:
`> auth actions {... authenticateUser: undefined ...}
> this.props.authenticateUser is not a function`

But I can see that the Redux Logger is running in the console which suggests `authenticateUser()` is running in `mapDispatchToProps`. So when the component mounts `authenticateUser()` isn't defined but is defined when mapDispatchToProps runs.

Comment: I'm really sorry, it actually should be `authenticateUser: () => dispatch(authActions.authenticateUser())` I don't know what I was think when I posted the anwser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153414/discussion-between-benjamin-hao-and-full-hybrid).

Answer (score 2):

I'll do a brief explanation about it to help you to understand those patterns and don't get in confusion anymore (I hope).

So, let's forget reducers for a moment to focus on **container**, **action creator** and **component** pattern.

### Component

A lot of people implement components by wrong way when using it with *redux* application.

A better component approach for redux is, implement it with *stateless* pattern (see [Functional Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)). Let's see in practice:

```
// components/Subscribe.js

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Subscribe = ({text, confirmSubscription}) =>
  <div>
    <p>{text}</p>
    <button onClick={confirmSubscription}>Confirm</button>
  </div>

Subscribe.propTypes = {
  subtitle: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

Subscribe.defaultProps = {
  subtitle: ''
}

export default Subtitle
```

This allows you to optimize component footprint because they have less features than *stateful components* (or class components), so you will win some performance and keep focused on component objective.

### Container

In other hand, *Container* is a kind of component with some logical implementation. Container is a pattern created to bind **React** and **Redux**, because both should't interact directly. This means, a Container render the component, handle some component events (for example, form `onSubmit`) and feed components with application state. So, the Container is the best place to interact with Redux. (react-redux)[https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux] and *Redux* make this task a bit easier. So a simple Container to feed and capture interactions on `Subscribe` component could be like this:

```
// containers/SubscribeContainer.js

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { confirmSubscription } from 'actions/subscription'
import Subscribe from 'components/Subscribe'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  text: state.subscription.text
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({
    confirmSubscription
  }, dispatch)

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default Container(Subscribe)
```

### Action Creator

An action creator (or action creators), is just a collection of or a function where return an action. Simple like that:

```
// actions/subscription

export const CONFIRM_SUBSCRIPTION = 'actions.confirmSubscription'

export function confirmSubscription() {
  return {
    type: CONFIRM_SUBSCRIPTION
  }
}
```

For now, we have the triad pattern, **Component**, **Container** and **Action Creator** implemented, from here, you just need two more things to make this working with **Redux**.

- Create a `subscription` store.
- Handle `CONFIRM_SUBSCRIPTION` (in case to update app's state)
- Return a new state

The magic will happen when you return a new state from any reducer, the `mapStateToProps` will be called and you will receive the new state as argument and from there, React will update your components when necessary, in case of those components are stateless, `PureComponent` (works only with single level states and props) or custom `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Another thing to keep on mind is to not do fetch or async execution inside **Components**, **Containers** and **Action Creators**, instead, you can use middleware like `redux-thunk` to compose a custom middeware to capture actions and handle that before be sent to reducers.